# Expresiones regulares lex para caracteres en español

Tags: regex

estoy tratando de generar un lexer para un lenguaje en el que determinados identificadores podrían tener caracteres españoles (Ñ, á, é, etc.)

Antes de añadir ese requisito la expresión regular era:

```
[_,a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

La nueva esta:

```
[_,a-zA-Z0-9ÑñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚçÇüÜ]+
```

Pues bien, he probado varios validadores de regex online e incluso con código y esa expresión funciona,pero no me funciona cuando la pongo en el fichero .l que pasa por lex (por plex en realidad, que el compilador está en  pascal)

Este es el fichero .l:

```
//This is the Lex (TPLex) lex file, the tokenizer

%{



%}
%%
\/CTL           BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_CTL, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno);  END;
\/STX           BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_STX, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno);  END;
\/CON           BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_CON, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
\/MTX           BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_MTX, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
\/LTX           BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_LTX, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
\/OTX           BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_OTX, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
\/OBJ           BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_OBJ, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
\/VOC           BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_VOC, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
\/PRO           BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_PRO, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
\/END           BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_END, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
#define         BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_DEFINE, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
#ifdef          BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_IFDEF, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
#ifndef         BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_IFNDEF, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
#endif          BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_ENDIF, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
#db             BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_DB, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
#extern         BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_EXTERN, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
#incbin         BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_INCBIN, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
#classic        BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_CLASSIC, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
\".*\"          BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_STRING, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
\'.*\''         BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_STRING, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
_               BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_UNDERSCORE, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
\/[0-9]+        BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_LIST_ENTRY, yytext, StrToInt(Copy(yytext,2,Length(yytext)-1)), yylineno, yycolno); END;
;.*\n           BEGIN  END;
-?[0-9]+        BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_NUMBER, yytext, StrToInt(yytext), yylineno, yycolno); END;
[_,a-zA-Z0-9ÑñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚçÇüÜ]+ BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_IDENTIFIER, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
\@              BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_INDIRECT, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
[ \t\n]         BEGIN  END;
.               BEGIN yyerror('Unexpected character'); Halt(1); END;
%%
```

Y este es el fichero lexer.pas que se genera:

```
(* lexical analyzer template (TP Lex V3.0), V1.0 3-2-91 AG *)

(* global definitions: *)
//This is the Lex (TPLex) lex file, the tokenizer





function yylex : Integer;

procedure yyaction ( yyruleno : Integer );
  (* local definitions: *)
begin
  (* actions: *)
  case yyruleno of
  1:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_CTL, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno);  END;
  2:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_STX, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno);  END;
  3:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_CON, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  4:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_MTX, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  5:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_LTX, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  6:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_OTX, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  7:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_OBJ, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  8:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_VOC, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  9:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_PRO, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  10:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_SECTION_END, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  11:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_DEFINE, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  12:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_IFDEF, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  13:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_IFNDEF, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  14:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_ENDIF, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  15:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_DB, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  16:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_EXTERN, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  17:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_INCBIN, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  18:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_CLASSIC, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  19:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_STRING, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  20:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_STRING, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  21:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_UNDERSCORE, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  22:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_LIST_ENTRY, yytext, StrToInt(Copy(yytext,2,Length(yytext)-1)), yylineno, yycolno); END;
  23:
                BEGIN  END;
  24:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_NUMBER, yytext, StrToInt(yytext), yylineno, yycolno); END;
  25:
                                               BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_IDENTIFIER, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  26:
                BEGIN  AddToken(TokenList, T_INDIRECT, yytext, MaxLongInt, yylineno, yycolno); END;
  27:
                BEGIN  END;
  28:
                BEGIN yyerror('Unexpected character'); Halt(1); END;
  end;
end(*yyaction*);

(* DFA table: *)

type YYTRec = record
                cc : set of Char;
                s  : Integer;
              end;

const

yynmarks   = 46;
yynmatches = 46;
yyntrans   = 121;
yynstates  = 92;

yyk : array [1..yynmarks] of Integer = (
  { 0: }
  { 1: }
  { 2: }
  28,
  { 3: }
  28,
  { 4: }
  28,
  { 5: }
  28,
  { 6: }
  21,
  25,
  28,
  { 7: }
  28,
  { 8: }
  28,
  { 9: }
  24,
  25,
  28,
  { 10: }
  25,
  28,
  { 11: }
  26,
  28,
  { 12: }
  27,
  { 13: }
  27,
  28,
  { 14: }
  28,
  { 15: }
  { 16: }
  { 17: }
  { 18: }
  { 19: }
  { 20: }
  { 21: }
  { 22: }
  { 23: }
  22,
  { 24: }
  { 25: }
  { 26: }
  { 27: }
  { 28: }
  { 29: }
  19,
  { 30: }
  { 31: }
  { 32: }
  25,
  { 33: }
  { 34: }
  23,
  { 35: }
  24,
  { 36: }
  24,
  25,
  { 37: }
  { 38: }
  { 39: }
  { 40: }
  { 41: }
  { 42: }
  { 43: }
  { 44: }
  { 45: }
  { 46: }
  { 47: }
  { 48: }
  15,
  { 49: }
  { 50: }
  { 51: }
  { 52: }
  { 53: }
  { 54: }
  20,
  { 55: }
  1,
  { 56: }
  3,
  { 57: }
  2,
  { 58: }
  4,
  { 59: }
  5,
  { 60: }
  6,
  { 61: }
  7,
  { 62: }
  8,
  { 63: }
  9,
  { 64: }
  10,
  { 65: }
  { 66: }
  { 67: }
  { 68: }
  { 69: }
  { 70: }
  { 71: }
  { 72: }
  { 73: }
  { 74: }
  { 75: }
  { 76: }
  { 77: }
  { 78: }
  { 79: }
  { 80: }
  12,
  { 81: }
  { 82: }
  { 83: }
  14,
  { 84: }
  { 85: }
  { 86: }
  11,
  { 87: }
  13,
  { 88: }
  17,
  { 89: }
  16,
  { 90: }
  { 91: }
  18
);

yym : array [1..yynmatches] of Integer = (
{ 0: }
{ 1: }
{ 2: }
  28,
{ 3: }
  28,
{ 4: }
  28,
{ 5: }
  28,
{ 6: }
  21,
  25,
  28,
{ 7: }
  28,
{ 8: }
  28,
{ 9: }
  24,
  25,
  28,
{ 10: }
  25,
  28,
{ 11: }
  26,
  28,
{ 12: }
  27,
{ 13: }
  27,
  28,
{ 14: }
  28,
{ 15: }
{ 16: }
{ 17: }
{ 18: }
{ 19: }
{ 20: }
{ 21: }
{ 22: }
{ 23: }
  22,
{ 24: }
{ 25: }
{ 26: }
{ 27: }
{ 28: }
{ 29: }
  19,
{ 30: }
{ 31: }
{ 32: }
  25,
{ 33: }
{ 34: }
  23,
{ 35: }
  24,
{ 36: }
  24,
  25,
{ 37: }
{ 38: }
{ 39: }
{ 40: }
{ 41: }
{ 42: }
{ 43: }
{ 44: }
{ 45: }
{ 46: }
{ 47: }
{ 48: }
  15,
{ 49: }
{ 50: }
{ 51: }
{ 52: }
{ 53: }
{ 54: }
  20,
{ 55: }
  1,
{ 56: }
  3,
{ 57: }
  2,
{ 58: }
  4,
{ 59: }
  5,
{ 60: }
  6,
{ 61: }
  7,
{ 62: }
  8,
{ 63: }
  9,
{ 64: }
  10,
{ 65: }
{ 66: }
{ 67: }
{ 68: }
{ 69: }
{ 70: }
{ 71: }
{ 72: }
{ 73: }
{ 74: }
{ 75: }
{ 76: }
{ 77: }
{ 78: }
{ 79: }
{ 80: }
  12,
{ 81: }
{ 82: }
{ 83: }
  14,
{ 84: }
{ 85: }
{ 86: }
  11,
{ 87: }
  13,
{ 88: }
  17,
{ 89: }
  16,
{ 90: }
{ 91: }
  18
);

yyt : array [1..yyntrans] of YYTrec = (
{ 0: }
  ( cc: [ #1..#8,#11..#31,'!','$'..'&','('..'+','.',
            ':','<'..'?','['..'^','`','{'..#128,#130..#134,
            #136,#138..#140,#142..#144,#146,#148..#153,
            #155,#157..#160,#162..#166,#168,#170..#172,
            #174..#176,#178,#180..#185,#187,#189..#194,
            #196..#255 ]; s: 14),
  ( cc: [ #9,' ' ]; s: 13),
  ( cc: [ #10 ]; s: 12),
  ( cc: [ '"' ]; s: 4),
  ( cc: [ '#' ]; s: 3),
  ( cc: [ '''' ]; s: 5),
  ( cc: [ ',','A'..'Z','a'..'z',#129,#135,#137,#141,
            #145,#147,#154,#156,#161,#167,#169,#173,#177,
            #179,#186,#188,#195 ]; s: 10),
  ( cc: [ '-' ]; s: 8),
  ( cc: [ '/' ]; s: 2),
  ( cc: [ '0'..'9' ]; s: 9),
  ( cc: [ ';' ]; s: 7),
  ( cc: [ '@' ]; s: 11),
  ( cc: [ '_' ]; s: 6),
{ 1: }
  ( cc: [ #1..#8,#11..#31,'!','$'..'&','('..'+','.',
            ':','<'..'?','['..'^','`','{'..#128,#130..#134,
            #136,#138..#140,#142..#144,#146,#148..#153,
            #155,#157..#160,#162..#166,#168,#170..#172,
            #174..#176,#178,#180..#185,#187,#189..#194,
            #196..#255 ]; s: 14),
  ( cc: [ #9,' ' ]; s: 13),
  ( cc: [ #10 ]; s: 12),
  ( cc: [ '"' ]; s: 4),
  ( cc: [ '#' ]; s: 3),
  ( cc: [ '''' ]; s: 5),
  ( cc: [ ',','A'..'Z','a'..'z',#129,#135,#137,#141,
            #145,#147,#154,#156,#161,#167,#169,#173,#177,
            #179,#186,#188,#195 ]; s: 10),
  ( cc: [ '-' ]; s: 8),
  ( cc: [ '/' ]; s: 2),
  ( cc: [ '0'..'9' ]; s: 9),
  ( cc: [ ';' ]; s: 7),
  ( cc: [ '@' ]; s: 11),
  ( cc: [ '_' ]; s: 6),
{ 2: }
  ( cc: [ '0'..'9' ]; s: 23),
  ( cc: [ 'C' ]; s: 15),
  ( cc: [ 'E' ]; s: 22),
  ( cc: [ 'L' ]; s: 18),
  ( cc: [ 'M' ]; s: 17),
  ( cc: [ 'O' ]; s: 19),
  ( cc: [ 'P' ]; s: 21),
  ( cc: [ 'S' ]; s: 16),
  ( cc: [ 'V' ]; s: 20),
{ 3: }
  ( cc: [ 'c' ]; s: 27),
  ( cc: [ 'd' ]; s: 24),
  ( cc: [ 'e' ]; s: 26),
  ( cc: [ 'i' ]; s: 25),
{ 4: }
  ( cc: [ #1..#9,#11..'!','#'..#255 ]; s: 28),
  ( cc: [ '"' ]; s: 29),
{ 5: }
  ( cc: [ #1..#9,#11..'&','('..#255 ]; s: 30),
  ( cc: [ '''' ]; s: 31),
{ 6: }
  ( cc: [ ',','0'..'9','A'..'Z','_','a'..'z',#129,#135,
            #137,#141,#145,#147,#154,#156,#161,#167,#169,
            #173,#177,#179,#186,#188,#195 ]; s: 32),
{ 7: }
  ( cc: [ #1..#9,#11..#255 ]; s: 33),
  ( cc: [ #10 ]; s: 34),
{ 8: }
  ( cc: [ '0'..'9' ]; s: 35),
{ 9: }
  ( cc: [ ',','A'..'Z','_','a'..'z',#129,#135,#137,
            #141,#145,#147,#154,#156,#161,#167,#169,#173,
            #177,#179,#186,#188,#195 ]; s: 32),
  ( cc: [ '0'..'9' ]; s: 36),
{ 10: }
  ( cc: [ ',','0'..'9','A'..'Z','_','a'..'z',#129,#135,
            #137,#141,#145,#147,#154,#156,#161,#167,#169,
            #173,#177,#179,#186,#188,#195 ]; s: 32),
{ 11: }
{ 12: }
{ 13: }
{ 14: }
{ 15: }
  ( cc: [ 'O' ]; s: 38),
  ( cc: [ 'T' ]; s: 37),
{ 16: }
  ( cc: [ 'T' ]; s: 39),
{ 17: }
  ( cc: [ 'T' ]; s: 40),
{ 18: }
  ( cc: [ 'T' ]; s: 41),
{ 19: }
  ( cc: [ 'B' ]; s: 43),
  ( cc: [ 'T' ]; s: 42),
{ 20: }
  ( cc: [ 'O' ]; s: 44),
{ 21: }
  ( cc: [ 'R' ]; s: 45),
{ 22: }
  ( cc: [ 'N' ]; s: 46),
{ 23: }
  ( cc: [ '0'..'9' ]; s: 23),
{ 24: }
  ( cc: [ 'b' ]; s: 48),
  ( cc: [ 'e' ]; s: 47),
{ 25: }
  ( cc: [ 'f' ]; s: 49),
  ( cc: [ 'n' ]; s: 50),
{ 26: }
  ( cc: [ 'n' ]; s: 51),
  ( cc: [ 'x' ]; s: 52),
{ 27: }
  ( cc: [ 'l' ]; s: 53),
{ 28: }
  ( cc: [ #1..#9,#11..'!','#'..#255 ]; s: 28),
  ( cc: [ '"' ]; s: 29),
{ 29: }
  ( cc: [ #1..#9,#11..'!','#'..#255 ]; s: 28),
  ( cc: [ '"' ]; s: 29),
{ 30: }
  ( cc: [ #1..#9,#11..'&','('..#255 ]; s: 30),
  ( cc: [ '''' ]; s: 31),
{ 31: }
  ( cc: [ #1..#9,#11..'&','('..#255 ]; s: 30),
  ( cc: [ '''' ]; s: 54),
{ 32: }
  ( cc: [ ',','0'..'9','A'..'Z','_','a'..'z',#129,#135,
            #137,#141,#145,#147,#154,#156,#161,#167,#169,
            #173,#177,#179,#186,#188,#195 ]; s: 32),
{ 33: }
  ( cc: [ #1..#9,#11..#255 ]; s: 33),
  ( cc: [ #10 ]; s: 34),
{ 34: }
{ 35: }
  ( cc: [ '0'..'9' ]; s: 35),
{ 36: }
  ( cc: [ ',','A'..'Z','_','a'..'z',#129,#135,#137,
            #141,#145,#147,#154,#156,#161,#167,#169,#173,
            #177,#179,#186,#188,#195 ]; s: 32),
  ( cc: [ '0'..'9' ]; s: 36),
{ 37: }
  ( cc: [ 'L' ]; s: 55),
{ 38: }
  ( cc: [ 'N' ]; s: 56),
{ 39: }
  ( cc: [ 'X' ]; s: 57),
{ 40: }
  ( cc: [ 'X' ]; s: 58),
{ 41: }
  ( cc: [ 'X' ]; s: 59),
{ 42: }
  ( cc: [ 'X' ]; s: 60),
{ 43: }
  ( cc: [ 'J' ]; s: 61),
{ 44: }
  ( cc: [ 'C' ]; s: 62),
{ 45: }
  ( cc: [ 'O' ]; s: 63),
{ 46: }
  ( cc: [ 'D' ]; s: 64),
{ 47: }
  ( cc: [ 'f' ]; s: 65),
{ 48: }
{ 49: }
  ( cc: [ 'd' ]; s: 66),
  ( cc: [ 'n' ]; s: 67),
{ 50: }
  ( cc: [ 'c' ]; s: 68),
{ 51: }
  ( cc: [ 'd' ]; s: 69),
{ 52: }
  ( cc: [ 't' ]; s: 70),
{ 53: }
  ( cc: [ 'a' ]; s: 71),
{ 54: }
  ( cc: [ #1..#9,#11..'&','('..#255 ]; s: 30),
  ( cc: [ '''' ]; s: 54),
{ 55: }
{ 56: }
{ 57: }
{ 58: }
{ 59: }
{ 60: }
{ 61: }
{ 62: }
{ 63: }
{ 64: }
{ 65: }
  ( cc: [ 'i' ]; s: 72),
{ 66: }
  ( cc: [ 'e' ]; s: 73),
{ 67: }
  ( cc: [ 'd' ]; s: 74),
{ 68: }
  ( cc: [ 'b' ]; s: 75),
{ 69: }
  ( cc: [ 'i' ]; s: 76),
{ 70: }
  ( cc: [ 'e' ]; s: 77),
{ 71: }
  ( cc: [ 's' ]; s: 78),
{ 72: }
  ( cc: [ 'n' ]; s: 79),
{ 73: }
  ( cc: [ 'f' ]; s: 80),
{ 74: }
  ( cc: [ 'e' ]; s: 81),
{ 75: }
  ( cc: [ 'i' ]; s: 82),
{ 76: }
  ( cc: [ 'f' ]; s: 83),
{ 77: }
  ( cc: [ 'r' ]; s: 84),
{ 78: }
  ( cc: [ 's' ]; s: 85),
{ 79: }
  ( cc: [ 'e' ]; s: 86),
{ 80: }
{ 81: }
  ( cc: [ 'f' ]; s: 87),
{ 82: }
  ( cc: [ 'n' ]; s: 88),
{ 83: }
{ 84: }
  ( cc: [ 'n' ]; s: 89),
{ 85: }
  ( cc: [ 'i' ]; s: 90),
{ 86: }
{ 87: }
{ 88: }
{ 89: }
{ 90: }
  ( cc: [ 'c' ]; s: 91)
{ 91: }
);

yykl : array [0..yynstates-1] of Integer = (
{ 0: } 1,
{ 1: } 1,
{ 2: } 1,
{ 3: } 2,
{ 4: } 3,
{ 5: } 4,
{ 6: } 5,
{ 7: } 8,
{ 8: } 9,
{ 9: } 10,
{ 10: } 13,
{ 11: } 15,
{ 12: } 17,
{ 13: } 18,
{ 14: } 20,
{ 15: } 21,
{ 16: } 21,
{ 17: } 21,
{ 18: } 21,
{ 19: } 21,
{ 20: } 21,
{ 21: } 21,
{ 22: } 21,
{ 23: } 21,
{ 24: } 22,
{ 25: } 22,
{ 26: } 22,
{ 27: } 22,
{ 28: } 22,
{ 29: } 22,
{ 30: } 23,
{ 31: } 23,
{ 32: } 23,
{ 33: } 24,
{ 34: } 24,
{ 35: } 25,
{ 36: } 26,
{ 37: } 28,
{ 38: } 28,
{ 39: } 28,
{ 40: } 28,
{ 41: } 28,
{ 42: } 28,
{ 43: } 28,
{ 44: } 28,
{ 45: } 28,
{ 46: } 28,
{ 47: } 28,
{ 48: } 28,
{ 49: } 29,
{ 50: } 29,
{ 51: } 29,
{ 52: } 29,
{ 53: } 29,
{ 54: } 29,
{ 55: } 30,
{ 56: } 31,
{ 57: } 32,
{ 58: } 33,
{ 59: } 34,
{ 60: } 35,
{ 61: } 36,
{ 62: } 37,
{ 63: } 38,
{ 64: } 39,
{ 65: } 40,
{ 66: } 40,
{ 67: } 40,
{ 68: } 40,
{ 69: } 40,
{ 70: } 40,
{ 71: } 40,
{ 72: } 40,
{ 73: } 40,
{ 74: } 40,
{ 75: } 40,
{ 76: } 40,
{ 77: } 40,
{ 78: } 40,
{ 79: } 40,
{ 80: } 40,
{ 81: } 41,
{ 82: } 41,
{ 83: } 41,
{ 84: } 42,
{ 85: } 42,
{ 86: } 42,
{ 87: } 43,
{ 88: } 44,
{ 89: } 45,
{ 90: } 46,
{ 91: } 46
);

yykh : array [0..yynstates-1] of Integer = (
{ 0: } 0,
{ 1: } 0,
{ 2: } 1,
{ 3: } 2,
{ 4: } 3,
{ 5: } 4,
{ 6: } 7,
{ 7: } 8,
{ 8: } 9,
{ 9: } 12,
{ 10: } 14,
{ 11: } 16,
{ 12: } 17,
{ 13: } 19,
{ 14: } 20,
{ 15: } 20,
{ 16: } 20,
{ 17: } 20,
{ 18: } 20,
{ 19: } 20,
{ 20: } 20,
{ 21: } 20,
{ 22: } 20,
{ 23: } 21,
{ 24: } 21,
{ 25: } 21,
{ 26: } 21,
{ 27: } 21,
{ 28: } 21,
{ 29: } 22,
{ 30: } 22,
{ 31: } 22,
{ 32: } 23,
{ 33: } 23,
{ 34: } 24,
{ 35: } 25,
{ 36: } 27,
{ 37: } 27,
{ 38: } 27,
{ 39: } 27,
{ 40: } 27,
{ 41: } 27,
{ 42: } 27,
{ 43: } 27,
{ 44: } 27,
{ 45: } 27,
{ 46: } 27,
{ 47: } 27,
{ 48: } 28,
{ 49: } 28,
{ 50: } 28,
{ 51: } 28,
{ 52: } 28,
{ 53: } 28,
{ 54: } 29,
{ 55: } 30,
{ 56: } 31,
{ 57: } 32,
{ 58: } 33,
{ 59: } 34,
{ 60: } 35,
{ 61: } 36,
{ 62: } 37,
{ 63: } 38,
{ 64: } 39,
{ 65: } 39,
{ 66: } 39,
{ 67: } 39,
{ 68: } 39,
{ 69: } 39,
{ 70: } 39,
{ 71: } 39,
{ 72: } 39,
{ 73: } 39,
{ 74: } 39,
{ 75: } 39,
{ 76: } 39,
{ 77: } 39,
{ 78: } 39,
{ 79: } 39,
{ 80: } 40,
{ 81: } 40,
{ 82: } 40,
{ 83: } 41,
{ 84: } 41,
{ 85: } 41,
{ 86: } 42,
{ 87: } 43,
{ 88: } 44,
{ 89: } 45,
{ 90: } 45,
{ 91: } 46
);

yyml : array [0..yynstates-1] of Integer = (
{ 0: } 1,
{ 1: } 1,
{ 2: } 1,
{ 3: } 2,
{ 4: } 3,
{ 5: } 4,
{ 6: } 5,
{ 7: } 8,
{ 8: } 9,
{ 9: } 10,
{ 10: } 13,
{ 11: } 15,
{ 12: } 17,
{ 13: } 18,
{ 14: } 20,
{ 15: } 21,
{ 16: } 21,
{ 17: } 21,
{ 18: } 21,
{ 19: } 21,
{ 20: } 21,
{ 21: } 21,
{ 22: } 21,
{ 23: } 21,
{ 24: } 22,
{ 25: } 22,
{ 26: } 22,
{ 27: } 22,
{ 28: } 22,
{ 29: } 22,
{ 30: } 23,
{ 31: } 23,
{ 32: } 23,
{ 33: } 24,
{ 34: } 24,
{ 35: } 25,
{ 36: } 26,
{ 37: } 28,
{ 38: } 28,
{ 39: } 28,
{ 40: } 28,
{ 41: } 28,
{ 42: } 28,
{ 43: } 28,
{ 44: } 28,
{ 45: } 28,
{ 46: } 28,
{ 47: } 28,
{ 48: } 28,
{ 49: } 29,
{ 50: } 29,
{ 51: } 29,
{ 52: } 29,
{ 53: } 29,
{ 54: } 29,
{ 55: } 30,
{ 56: } 31,
{ 57: } 32,
{ 58: } 33,
{ 59: } 34,
{ 60: } 35,
{ 61: } 36,
{ 62: } 37,
{ 63: } 38,
{ 64: } 39,
{ 65: } 40,
{ 66: } 40,
{ 67: } 40,
{ 68: } 40,
{ 69: } 40,
{ 70: } 40,
{ 71: } 40,
{ 72: } 40,
{ 73: } 40,
{ 74: } 40,
{ 75: } 40,
{ 76: } 40,
{ 77: } 40,
{ 78: } 40,
{ 79: } 40,
{ 80: } 40,
{ 81: } 41,
{ 82: } 41,
{ 83: } 41,
{ 84: } 42,
{ 85: } 42,
{ 86: } 42,
{ 87: } 43,
{ 88: } 44,
{ 89: } 45,
{ 90: } 46,
{ 91: } 46
);

yymh : array [0..yynstates-1] of Integer = (
{ 0: } 0,
{ 1: } 0,
{ 2: } 1,
{ 3: } 2,
{ 4: } 3,
{ 5: } 4,
{ 6: } 7,
{ 7: } 8,
{ 8: } 9,
{ 9: } 12,
{ 10: } 14,
{ 11: } 16,
{ 12: } 17,
{ 13: } 19,
{ 14: } 20,
{ 15: } 20,
{ 16: } 20,
{ 17: } 20,
{ 18: } 20,
{ 19: } 20,
{ 20: } 20,
{ 21: } 20,
{ 22: } 20,
{ 23: } 21,
{ 24: } 21,
{ 25: } 21,
{ 26: } 21,
{ 27: } 21,
{ 28: } 21,
{ 29: } 22,
{ 30: } 22,
{ 31: } 22,
{ 32: } 23,
{ 33: } 23,
{ 34: } 24,
{ 35: } 25,
{ 36: } 27,
{ 37: } 27,
{ 38: } 27,
{ 39: } 27,
{ 40: } 27,
{ 41: } 27,
{ 42: } 27,
{ 43: } 27,
{ 44: } 27,
{ 45: } 27,
{ 46: } 27,
{ 47: } 27,
{ 48: } 28,
{ 49: } 28,
{ 50: } 28,
{ 51: } 28,
{ 52: } 28,
{ 53: } 28,
{ 54: } 29,
{ 55: } 30,
{ 56: } 31,
{ 57: } 32,
{ 58: } 33,
{ 59: } 34,
{ 60: } 35,
{ 61: } 36,
{ 62: } 37,
{ 63: } 38,
{ 64: } 39,
{ 65: } 39,
{ 66: } 39,
{ 67: } 39,
{ 68: } 39,
{ 69: } 39,
{ 70: } 39,
{ 71: } 39,
{ 72: } 39,
{ 73: } 39,
{ 74: } 39,
{ 75: } 39,
{ 76: } 39,
{ 77: } 39,
{ 78: } 39,
{ 79: } 39,
{ 80: } 40,
{ 81: } 40,
{ 82: } 40,
{ 83: } 41,
{ 84: } 41,
{ 85: } 41,
{ 86: } 42,
{ 87: } 43,
{ 88: } 44,
{ 89: } 45,
{ 90: } 45,
{ 91: } 46
);

yytl : array [0..yynstates-1] of Integer = (
{ 0: } 1,
{ 1: } 14,
{ 2: } 27,
{ 3: } 36,
{ 4: } 40,
{ 5: } 42,
{ 6: } 44,
{ 7: } 45,
{ 8: } 47,
{ 9: } 48,
{ 10: } 50,
{ 11: } 51,
{ 12: } 51,
{ 13: } 51,
{ 14: } 51,
{ 15: } 51,
{ 16: } 53,
{ 17: } 54,
{ 18: } 55,
{ 19: } 56,
{ 20: } 58,
{ 21: } 59,
{ 22: } 60,
{ 23: } 61,
{ 24: } 62,
{ 25: } 64,
{ 26: } 66,
{ 27: } 68,
{ 28: } 69,
{ 29: } 71,
{ 30: } 73,
{ 31: } 75,
{ 32: } 77,
{ 33: } 78,
{ 34: } 80,
{ 35: } 80,
{ 36: } 81,
{ 37: } 83,
{ 38: } 84,
{ 39: } 85,
{ 40: } 86,
{ 41: } 87,
{ 42: } 88,
{ 43: } 89,
{ 44: } 90,
{ 45: } 91,
{ 46: } 92,
{ 47: } 93,
{ 48: } 94,
{ 49: } 94,
{ 50: } 96,
{ 51: } 97,
{ 52: } 98,
{ 53: } 99,
{ 54: } 100,
{ 55: } 102,
{ 56: } 102,
{ 57: } 102,
{ 58: } 102,
{ 59: } 102,
{ 60: } 102,
{ 61: } 102,
{ 62: } 102,
{ 63: } 102,
{ 64: } 102,
{ 65: } 102,
{ 66: } 103,
{ 67: } 104,
{ 68: } 105,
{ 69: } 106,
{ 70: } 107,
{ 71: } 108,
{ 72: } 109,
{ 73: } 110,
{ 74: } 111,
{ 75: } 112,
{ 76: } 113,
{ 77: } 114,
{ 78: } 115,
{ 79: } 116,
{ 80: } 117,
{ 81: } 117,
{ 82: } 118,
{ 83: } 119,
{ 84: } 119,
{ 85: } 120,
{ 86: } 121,
{ 87: } 121,
{ 88: } 121,
{ 89: } 121,
{ 90: } 121,
{ 91: } 122
);

yyth : array [0..yynstates-1] of Integer = (
{ 0: } 13,
{ 1: } 26,
{ 2: } 35,
{ 3: } 39,
{ 4: } 41,
{ 5: } 43,
{ 6: } 44,
{ 7: } 46,
{ 8: } 47,
{ 9: } 49,
{ 10: } 50,
{ 11: } 50,
{ 12: } 50,
{ 13: } 50,
{ 14: } 50,
{ 15: } 52,
{ 16: } 53,
{ 17: } 54,
{ 18: } 55,
{ 19: } 57,
{ 20: } 58,
{ 21: } 59,
{ 22: } 60,
{ 23: } 61,
{ 24: } 63,
{ 25: } 65,
{ 26: } 67,
{ 27: } 68,
{ 28: } 70,
{ 29: } 72,
{ 30: } 74,
{ 31: } 76,
{ 32: } 77,
{ 33: } 79,
{ 34: } 79,
{ 35: } 80,
{ 36: } 82,
{ 37: } 83,
{ 38: } 84,
{ 39: } 85,
{ 40: } 86,
{ 41: } 87,
{ 42: } 88,
{ 43: } 89,
{ 44: } 90,
{ 45: } 91,
{ 46: } 92,
{ 47: } 93,
{ 48: } 93,
{ 49: } 95,
{ 50: } 96,
{ 51: } 97,
{ 52: } 98,
{ 53: } 99,
{ 54: } 101,
{ 55: } 101,
{ 56: } 101,
{ 57: } 101,
{ 58: } 101,
{ 59: } 101,
{ 60: } 101,
{ 61: } 101,
{ 62: } 101,
{ 63: } 101,
{ 64: } 101,
{ 65: } 102,
{ 66: } 103,
{ 67: } 104,
{ 68: } 105,
{ 69: } 106,
{ 70: } 107,
{ 71: } 108,
{ 72: } 109,
{ 73: } 110,
{ 74: } 111,
{ 75: } 112,
{ 76: } 113,
{ 77: } 114,
{ 78: } 115,
{ 79: } 116,
{ 80: } 116,
{ 81: } 117,
{ 82: } 118,
{ 83: } 118,
{ 84: } 119,
{ 85: } 120,
{ 86: } 120,
{ 87: } 120,
{ 88: } 120,
{ 89: } 120,
{ 90: } 121,
{ 91: } 121
);


var yyn : Integer;

label start, scan, action;

begin

start:

  (* initialize: *)

  yynew;

scan:

  (* mark positions and matches: *)

  for yyn := yykl[yystate] to     yykh[yystate] do yymark(yyk[yyn]);
  for yyn := yymh[yystate] downto yyml[yystate] do yymatch(yym[yyn]);

  if yytl[yystate]>yyth[yystate] then goto action; (* dead state *)

  (* get next character: *)

  yyscan;

  (* determine action: *)

  yyn := yytl[yystate];
  while (yyn<=yyth[yystate]) and not (yyactchar in yyt[yyn].cc) do inc(yyn);
  if yyn>yyth[yystate] then goto action;
    (* no transition on yyactchar in this state *)

  (* switch to new state: *)

  yystate := yyt[yyn].s;

  goto scan;

action:

  (* execute action: *)

  if yyfind(yyrule) then
    begin
      yyaction(yyrule);
      if yyreject then goto action;
    end
  else if not yydefault and yywrap() then
    begin
      yyclear;
      return(0);
    end;

  if not yydone then goto start;

  yylex := yyretval;

end(*yylex*);
```

Alguna idea de qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: @Uto dev Bienvenido, estas en stackoverflow ES, por lo que te recomendaría que pusieras la pregunta en español si no es mucha molestia, y así tendrás una mejor ayuda por parte de la comunidad.

Comment: Debes traducir tu pregunta. Para ello, pulsa en [edit] y traducela. De esa manera probablemente recibas la respuesta que buscas :)

Comment: Gracias por el aviso, la verdad es que ni me fijé que estaba en stackoverflow en español, di por hecho que estaba en el inglés y me lancé. Ya está traducida

Answer (score 2):

¡Un rompecabezas sobre encodings! Mis favoritos :-)

## Indagaciones previas

Mi hipótesis era que el código fuente que has escrito en el archivo `.l` había sido escrito en disco con un encoding que estaba confundiendo al lexer. Por ejemplo UTF-8.

Si el lexer no está preparado para tratar con UTF-8 y decodificarlo correctamente como Unicode, se encontrará con problemas, y que un texto como `Ñ`, codificado en UTF8 son en realidad dos bytes en tu fuente: `0xC3` y `0xB1` (que en decimal serían respectivamente 195 y 177).

Esto haría que el lexer generado busque un byte de valor `195` o bien `177` para considerarlo carácter válido, en lugar de una Ñ.

Para verificar esta hipótesis me fijo en que, en el código de `lexer.pas` aparece en varias ocasiones un código como el siguiente:

```
{ 6: }
  ( cc: [ ',','0'..'9','A'..'Z','_','a'..'z',#129,#135,
            #137,#141,#145,#147,#154,#156,#161,#167,#169,
            #173,#177,#179,#186,#188,#195 ]; s: 32),
```

donde se ve la familiar secuencia de caracteres `'0'..'9', 'A'..'Z'`, etc. seguida de una ristra de números como `#129, #135, #137` que tienen una pinta bastante sospechosa. De hecho, en esa rsitra aparecen los números 177 y 195 que, como indiqué antes, serían parte de la codificación UTF-8 de la Ñ.

Para terminar de verificar mi hipótesis, convierto a UTF-8 la parte no-ascii de tu expresión regular, es decir: `'ÑñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚçÇüÜ'`, para seguidamente extraer los bytes de esa conversión y escribir sus valores (eliminando repeticiones, pues el byte 195 aparece como prefijo muchas veces), ordenados de menor a mayor.

Esto lo hago con la siguiente línea python:

```
>>> sorted(set('ÑñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚçÇüÜ'.encode("utf8")))
[129, 135, 137, 141, 145, 147, 154, 156, 161, 167, 169, 173, 177, 179, 186, 188, 195]
```

Y ¡bingo! son los mismos números que aparecen por doquier en `lexer.pas`

## Conclusión

El lexer no está preparado para UTF-8, y el problema proviene de que este encoding usa dos bytes para representar cada caracter no-ascii (al menos si nos restringimos al conjunto de letras que quieres permitir, ya que en principio Unicode soporta también chino, japonés, etc. y en ellos cada caracter serían 3 bytes).

## Posible solución

Cíñete a un *encoding* que use **un solo byte por carácter**, como ISO-8859-1.

Es decir, escribe tu fichero `.l` con un editor que te permita guardar en ISO-8859-1, y guárdalo con ese encoding. El `lexer.pas` seguirá mostrando "números raros" en lugar de esos caracteres, pero conjeturo que eso no sería problema ahora para parsear correctamente un fichero de entrada *con tal de que el fichero también use ISO-8859-1*.

Fíjate en la última frase, porque es crucial. Los usuarios de tu lenguaje están obligados a guardar su código fuente en ISO-8859-1. Si lo guardan en UTF-8 no funcionará.

Comment: ¡Gracias!. La verdad es que al final conseguí solucionarlo, o mejor dicho se ha solucionado solo al arreglar otro problema. En cualquier caso, el problema era exáctamente el que dices, y se ha solucionado solo porque me di cuenta de que la librería LibLex de freepascal usa el tipo String clásico de Turbo Pascal (255 de longitud máxima) y eso hacía que algunas cadenas del lenguaje se cortaran. Al cambiarlo a AnsiString, inmediatamente me coge las strigns largas y los caracteres españoles, porque AnsiString, o las funciones que lo usan, son capaces de manejar esos chars de doble-byte.